# Java - extensible Visitor alternative

Tags: java, visitor-pattern

Is there an design pattern in Java that achieves the same aim as Visitor, but without the Visitor implementation needing to know all possible types it needs to overload `visit()` on at compile time?

I want to allow users of my code to add new *visitable* classes. I can imagine that they'd then create a visitor implementation as well, and register this with some sort of registry that says "hey, `RedVisitable` wants to be visited - who's the class for that job?". However, as the implementations of the pattern I've seen depend on overloading, I'm not sure how this would be achievable.

Comment: What would happen with previous visitor implementations unaware of the new class?

Comment: Thanks for reading. I was hoping to have _one_ implementation of the strategy the `Visitor` would use per `Visitable` - otherwise I'd end up with one all-knowing class that knows about all the `Visitable`s in the system.

Comment: You probably could take a look at how hibernate validator "registers" custom validators

Comment: Reflection can achieve that. In a similar way to how guava's [EventBus](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/EventBusExplained#why-use-an-annotation-to-mark-handler-methods-rather-than-requiring-the-listener-to-implement-an-interface) can forward events to methods based on their method parameter type.

Comment: Maybe if you tweak the pattern a bit. Instead of overloading your `Visitor`, have one method only for a common interface implementing `visit()` that would be implemented by the `Visitable`'s. This of course assumes each `Visitable` would have to be autonomous when implementing their own `visit()`. Would that be possible?

Comment: Tiny reflective example http://ideone.com/XKeYmH - the biggest drawback is that this doesn't work with generic types as target. Method parameters keep the generic type information, but the visited objects loose theirs due to erasure. You could maybe solve that by requiring type tokens that keep type at runtime (e.g. pass them to the visit method every time a generic object needs to be visited).